# Mips: unable to get label to work for assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

## here is the code i have:

```
hex:    bne $a0,$t1,elseif 
    li $t1,1
        li $t2,2
        li $v0,1       
        jr $ra         
  
elseif: bne $a0, $t2,else
        li $v0,6
        jr $ra
  
else:   addi $sp,$sp,-12
    sw $ra,$ra 0($sp) -
    addi $t3,$a0,-1   ~
    sll $t3, $t2,1
    sw $a0,$a0,4($sp) -
    sw $t3,8($sp)
    lw $ra            -
    lw $a0            -
    addi $t3,4
    sub $t4,$t3,$t0
    lw $t4             -
    sw $v0,$t4         -
    lw $ra             -
    lw $a0             -
    j $ra
```

## what i am trying to do:

```
 if (n == 1)
   return 1
 else if (n == 2)
   return 6
 else
   return 2*hex(n-1) - hex(n-2) + 4
```

## Problem: I don't fully understand how the stack(else: label) works or why Recursion is needed in the lable